# IsNullOrEmpty equivalent for Array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a function in the .NET library that will return true or false as to whether an array is null or empty? (Similar to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`).

I had a look in the `Array` class for a function such as this but couldn't see anything.

i.e.

```
var a = new string[]{};
string[] b = null;
var c = new string[]{"hello"};

IsNullOrEmpty(a); //returns true
IsNullOrEmpty(b); //returns true
IsNullOrEmpty(c); //returns false
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if (arr != null && arr.Length != 0)`? Or create an extension method if you need to use this repeatedly.

Comment: @CodyGray same thing that's wrong with it for strings, you don't want to do that all over the place.

Comment: @CodyGray - I agree, but I can see it becoming a pain to write if you had to write it repeatedly. I've got an extension method in most of my projects that does exactly this.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Really? Why not? I don't see how that's any more difficult than `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`...

Comment: @CodyGray - The difference is that an extension method means typing 2 or 3 characters and then using IntelliSense to autocomplete. You have to write `if (arr != null && arr.Length != 0)` in its entirety.

Comment: Fascinating, making coding decisions based on IntelliSense. I guess that's not how I write code. Maybe I'm old school. Nothing wrong with your way either, though.

Comment: @CodyGray I believe `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is optimized by the compiler to be faster than an `if`.

Comment: @Yuriy: No, there's no special optimization going on there as far as I'm aware of. To begin with, the compiler does very little optimizing in C#. Almost all optimizations are handled by the JITer at run-time. Yes, it's quite likely that such a short method would be inlined by the JITer, but there's no guarantee. But even if that happened, there'd be no difference between the method call and the above code. There's nothing magic going on inside of the `IsNullOrEmpty` method—it's just there for convenience reasons. Early versions of the JITer actually had problems getting the optimization right.

Comment: @CodyGray right, I meant the JIT Compiler. So they took it out?

Comment: @Yuriy: It was never there. The "optimization" happening in early versions was a removal of the check for `null`. Since that obviously caused programs calling the method to crash with a `NullReferenceException`, yes they took that out. There's no way to optimize the code further than the two simple checks. The `&&` operator already performs short-circuiting, which is all the optimization you're going to get. If the method is inlined, you lose nothing. If not, it's going to be marginally slower (probably not relevant). But there's no way that writing the code explicitly could be any slower.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There isn't an existing one, but you could use this extension method:

```
/// <summary>Indicates whether the specified array is null or has a length of zero.</summary>
/// <param name="array">The array to test.</param>
/// <returns>true if the array parameter is null or has a length of zero; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this Array array)
{
    return (array == null || array.Length == 0);
}
```

Just place this in an extensions class somewhere and it'll extend `Array` to have an `IsNullOrEmpty` method.

Comment: Given either of the variables (a,b or c) could you demonstrate it's usage?

The only way I can see it working is new Array().IsNullOrEmpty(a);

Comment: No need for the parenthesis. Also you're overriding the normal behavior of what happens when you call a method on a null instance, so I'd put some xml comments for intellisense.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich - Yeah, the parenthesis are just a habit really. Feels wierd to me if I have combining logic without them. You're correct on the null behaviour, so I'll update.

Comment: @maxp - It's an extension method. You call it directly on the object, like `a.IsNullOrEmpty()`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: If it really bothers you to call an extension method on a possibly null reference, you can also use the syntax `ExtensionClass.IsNullOrEmpty(arr)` (which is what the compiler is effectively doing), but that's not the normal way of using an extension method.

Answer (score 43):

With [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) introduced in VS 2015, the opposite Is**Not**NullOrEmpty can be:

```
if (array?.Length > 0) {           // similar to if (array != null && array.Length > 0) {
```

but the `IsNullOrEmpty` version looks a bit ugly because of the operator precedence:

```
if (!(array?.Length > 0)) {
```

Answer (score 39):

You could create your own extension method:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this T[] array)
{
    return array == null || array.Length == 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually like this answer better than mine :)

Comment: @Polynomial which version of .net? Simply doing `new int[0].IsNullOrEmpty<int>()` throws an exception for me. But that works with yours. Now if you declare it any other way, it works fine.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich - Running .NET 4.0.30319 on Win7 x64, works fine regardless of whether I use `<int>` or let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: Never mind, now it works for some reason. I assume I made some mistake.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich - Probably a bit late on this comment, but I think you're missing brackets; i.e. `(new int[0]).IsNullOrEmpty<int>();`

Comment: Polynomial's answer results in a conflict with another existing extension method I use: `error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.ExtensionMethods.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Array)' and 'System.Collections.Generic.ExtensionMethods.IsNullOrEmpty<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'` - so I like this answer better.

Answer (score 10):

More generic if you use `ICollection<T>`:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T> (this ICollection<T> collection)
{
    return collection == null || collection.Count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an updated C# 8 version of the (currently) up-voted answer

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>([NotNullWhen(false)] this T[]? array) =>
    array == null || array.Length == 0;
```

Comment: Info on NotNullWhen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Answer (score 4):

```
if (array?.Any() != true) { ... }
```

- Don't forget having `using System.Linq;`
- Note one must explicitly compare against `true` since the underlying type is `bool?`

Answer (score 3):

In case you initialized you array like

```
string[] myEmpytArray = new string[4];
```

Then to check if your array elements are empty use

```
myEmpytArray .All(item => item == null)
```

Try

```
 public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T> (this ICollection<T> collection)
 {
    if (collection == null || collection.Count == 0)
        return true;
    else
       return collection.All(item => item == null);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Any` on creating your extension method:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this T[] array) where T : class
    {
        return (array == null || !array.Any());
    }
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` on your using statements.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can write it yourself as an extension method. Or a static method in your own library, if you don't like calling methods on a null type.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 6.0, the null-propagation operator may be used to express concise like this:

```
if (array?.Count.Equals(0) ?? true)
```

> **Note 1:** `?? false` is necessary, because of the [following reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667306/4469405)
>
> **Note 2:** as a bonus, the statement [is also "thread-safe"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40977007/4469405)

Answer (score 0):

Checking for null or empty or Length has been simplified with C# Linq. With null coalesce operator, one can simply do this:

```
if (array?.Any())
    return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: _"Cannot implicitly convert 'bool?' to 'bool'"_