# Does C# have IsNullOrEmpty for List/IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, isnullorempty

I know generally empty List is more prefer than NULL. But I am going to return NULL, for mainly two reasons

1. I have to check and handle null values explicitly, avoiding bugs and attacks.
2. It is easy to perform `??` operation afterwards to get a return value.

For strings, we have IsNullOrEmpty. Is there anything **from C# itself** doing the same thing for List or IEnumerable?

Comment: No but adding an extension method is trivial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if IEnumerable is null or empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047349/how-to-check-if-ienumerable-is-null-or-empty)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

nothing baked into the framework, but it's a pretty straight forward extension method.

[See here](http://danielvaughan.org/posts/.net/collections/2010/04/18/IEnumerable-IsNullOrEmpty/)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the collection is null or contains no elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The IEnumerable type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">The enumerable, which may be null or empty.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the IEnumerable is null or empty; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        /* If this is a list, use the Count property for efficiency. 
         * The Count property is O(1) while IEnumerable.Count() is O(N). */
        var collection = enumerable as ICollection<T>;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            return collection.Count < 1;
        }
        return !enumerable.Any(); 
    }
```

Daniel Vaughan takes the extra step of casting to ICollection (where possible) for performance reasons.  Something I would not have thought to do.

Comment: Caution must be taken though that the call to `enumerable.Any()` can lose an element of a non-rewindable enumeration. You can wrap it in something that'll keep track of that first element (and handle null nicely of course or we negate the OP's whole issue), but it can be handier in some cases to coalesce with an empty enumeration and just use the result.

Comment: Uh, am I daft or should the last line of that function be `return !enumerable.Any();` ?  I'll edit it.

Comment: Should one also try casting to non-generic `ICollection`, since an `IEnumerable<Animal>` might be something like an instance of `List<Cat>`, which does not implement `ICollection<Animal>` but does implement non-generic `ICollection`?

Comment: This doesn't work for XmlNodeList? XmlNodeList is also implementing the IEnumerable interface, why doesn't work this?

Comment: as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (check remarks) "The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined." wich makes me think a cast to collection is unnecessary as enumerable.Any() should have O(1) as well. so why cast to a list if you don't really know it is a list?

Comment: The comment about "IEnumerable.Count() is O(N)" is correct... *but* the code isn't doing that, it's calling `Any()`. Although it's still a good idea to cast so that you can avoid the `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` code under the hood when calling `Any`.

Comment: This could now be written in one line: return a == null || ((a as ICollection)?.Count == 0) || !a.Any();

Comment: Casting to ICollection is correct and good practice in general. All Linq methods implementations use casting to optimize performance. However, in this case, it is not necessary at all, as Any method internally will just call MoveNext only once.

Comment: I just realized that this solution omits a short-circuit for `IReadOnlyCollection` (which does _not_ inherit from ICollection).

Comment: Stupid out-of-topic-question: Why is `ICollection.Count` O(1) and `IEnumerable.Count()` O(n)? I undestand the latter one, but why is a simple cast enough to make it O(1)?

Comment: @ElMac The spec of ICollection.Count is that the count is tracked, any implementation should return the count without iterating the values to calculate it on demand. But as another person said in comments, the same optimisation should also be called for IReadOnlyCollection. Also, LINQ.Any uses the optimisation on ICollection, but not on IReadOnlyCollection.

Answer (score 61):

**Late update**: since C# 6.0, the *null-propagation operator* may be used to express concise like this:

```
if (  list?.Count  > 0 ) // For List<T>
if ( array?.Length > 0 ) // For Array<T>
```

or, as a cleaner and more generic alternative for `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
if ( enumerable?.Any() ?? false )
```

---

**Note 1:** all upper variants reflect actually `IsNotNullOrEmpty`, in contrast to OP question ([quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41596301/4469405)):

> Because of operator precedence `IsNullOrEmpty` equivalents look less appealing:
>   `if (!(list?.Count > 0))`

**Note 2:** `?? false` is necessary, because of the following reason (summary/quote from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666993/c-sharp-null-propagating-operator-conditional-access-expression-if-blocks?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

> `?.` operator will return `null` if a child member is `null`.
>   But [...] if we try to get a non-`Nullable` member, like the
>   `Any()` method, that returns `bool` [...] the compiler will
>   "wrap" a return value in `Nullable<>`. For example, `Object?.Any()` will
>   give us `bool?` (which is `Nullable<bool>`), not `bool`. 
>   [...] Since it can't be implicitly casted to `bool` this expression cannot be used in the `if`

**Note 3:** as a bonus, the statement is also "thread-safe" (quote from answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976947/null-propagation-replacement-for-null-check-prior-conditional-statement)):

> In a multithreaded context, if [*enumerable*] is accessible from another
>   thread (either because it's a field that's accessible or because it's
>   closed over in a lambda that is exposed to another thread) then the
>   value could be different each time it's computed [*i.e.prior null-check*]

Comment: @GrimR3 Yes, you're right: that's more strait to the question. I've written it like that to be inline with the quote/referece.

Comment: You can check for 0 or 1 elements with this: `(myArray?.Length ?? 0) < 2`

Answer (score 27):

There is nothing built in.

It is a simple extension method though:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
  if(enumerable == null)
    return true;

  return !enumerable.Any();
}
```

Comment: I wonder why both this and the accepted answer both missed the ! before the Any() call. That same bug got propagated into my team's source code.

Answer (score 11):

```
var nullOrEmpty = list == null || !list.Any();
```

Answer (score 4):

Putting together the previous answers into a simple extension method for C# 6.0+:

```
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> me) => !me?.Any() ?? true;
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has said, nothing is built into the framework, but if you are using Castle then Castle.Core.Internal has it.

```
using Castle.Core.Internal;

namespace PhoneNumbers
{
    public class PhoneNumberService : IPhoneNumberService
    {
        public void ConsolidateNumbers(Account accountRequest)
        {
            if (accountRequest.Addresses.IsNullOrEmpty()) // Addresses is List<T>
            {
                return;
            }
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to retrieve all of the elements in the case of it not being empty, then some of the answers here won't work, because the call to `Any()` on a non-rewindable enumerable will "forget" an element.

You could take a different approach and turn nulls into empties:

```
bool didSomething = false;
foreach(var element in someEnumeration ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyType>())
{
  //some sensible thing to do on element...
  didSomething = true;
}
if(!didSomething)
{
  //handle the fact that it was null or empty (without caring which).
}
```

Likewise `(someEnumeration ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyType>()).ToList()` etc. can be used.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a non-rewindable collection in .NET?  I mean just name of an existing class in the framework, not asking you to give me an example implementation of one.

Comment: @AaronLS the result of most Linq queries.

Comment: What would be the concrete type in that case? I'm aware of IQueryable which isn't really a list until you try to ToList/foreach at which point it materialized.  I imagine there is some intermediate concrete type for IQueryable that is a forward only data reader under the hood, so what you say makes sense, I just can't imagine where you'd actually encounter this problem. If you `foreach(var item in someQueryable)` would generate its own eneumerator, and then did `someQueryable.Any()` would be a seperate query and wouldn't affect the current foreach enumerator AFAIK.

Comment: Not challenging you, just trying to explain my confusion.

Comment: @AaronLS it would be a separate enumerator, which would require you to run the query again, which is bad enough. If it was cast to `IEnumerable` then even more so, as the query will have been lost.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the suggestion from Matthew Vines to avoid the "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" - problem.
(see also the comment from Jon Hanna)

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable items)
    => items == null
    || (items as ICollection)?.Count == 0
    || !items.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```

... and the unit test:

```
[Test]
public void TestEnumerableEx()
{
    List<int> list = null;
    Assert.IsTrue(list.IsNullOrEmpty());

    list = new List<int>();
    Assert.IsTrue(list.IsNullOrEmpty());

    list.AddRange(new []{1, 2, 3});
    Assert.IsFalse(list.IsNullOrEmpty());

    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
    for(var i = 1; i <= list.Count; i++)
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(list.IsNullOrEmpty());
        Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());
        Assert.AreEqual(i, enumerator.Current);
    }

    Assert.IsFalse(list.IsNullOrEmpty());
    Assert.IsFalse(enumerator.MoveNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nullOrEmpty = !( list?.Count > 0 );
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers, try adding a few lines explaining what the problem was and how your code fixes it

Comment: This won't compile if list is IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

for me best isNullOrEmpty method is looked like this

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return !enumerable?.Any() ?? true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static class IEnumerableExtention
 {
     public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
     {
         if (enumerable == null)
         {
             return true;
         }
 
         using var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
 
         var isEmpty = !enumerator.MoveNext();
 
         return isEmpty;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One-line with nullable support:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T>? enumerable) => 
            enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
```