# Correct way to check if a variable is null or empty

Tags: c#, null

I have the following code which a colleague of mine told me is incorrect and will crash if my variable is null:

```
List<FSKUser> users = null;

if (users == null || users.Count() == 0)
{
   return false;
}
```

Obviously the `=null` is just for testing purpose.  But when I run this code it runs correctly and returns false.

Is the way I'm checking a safe and correct way to check?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582344/does-c-sharp-have-isnullorempty-for-list-ienumerable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047349/how-to-check-if-ienumerable-is-null-or-empty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the safe and correct way. Your colleague probably has some weird understanding of operator precedence or boolean expression evaluation in C# :)

The `||` operator (the same as `&&`) will stop evaluating as soon as it can be sure of the results. Since boolean OR can never yield `false` as soon as one of the operands is `true`, it will *either* fail on the first operand (if it's null, the result is `true` => you're done), or it will evaluate both of the operators.

Of course, if you're not averse to using extension methods, this can be handily used to simplify the condition. Eg. you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(List<T> @this)
{
  return @this == null || @this.Count == 0;
}
```

Which then lets you use a condition like this:

```
if (users.IsEmpty())
{
  ...
}
```

Also, note that `List<T>` has a `Count` property - you should probably use that instead of the extension method `Count()`. In the end, it will do the same thing IIRC (it checks if the enumerable is a collection or a list, IIRC), but it goes through some loops to do that.

You might want to ask your colleague what he thinks will happen. You've got a simple test case that shows you're right, but perhaps he's got some reasons of his own why he doesn't want that. The most likely thing, however, is that he's used to a different programming language, and not actually a native C#-er. In that case, you've both gotten an opportunity to learn :)

Comment: I wanted to say he should use the `.Count` property (no parentheses) as well. It is fast with a `List<>`. The Linq extension will discover that this is an `ICollection<>` and use the `Count` property as well. However, if you want Linq, use `.Any()` instead since it is shorter, more precise, and can be faster when the underlying source is **not** a `List<>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is wrong. The `||` operator **short-circuits** - it exits with `true` the first time any term returns `true`. Similarly, the `&&` operator exits with `false` the first time any term returns `false`. As such, your `users.Count()` **cannot** be reached if `users` is `null` (unless, perhaps, `users` is a field and you are doing lots of threading, and the compiler and JIT both choose to explicitly load the field twice for some reason).

Comment: Funny, I WAS going to downvote this answer, but after some thought I realized it answers the OP's question as asked and explains why. While the accepted answer is great - and I was going to upvote it - it wasn't exactly what the OP asked. Upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. The 2nd condition will only be evaluated if users does not equal `null`, so this is the correct way to check against null.

In contrast to other languages (VB.NET and the `And` and `Or` operator as opposed to `AndAlso` and `OrElse`), C# only evaluates conditions as long as their result has an impact on the overall result. If - as in your case - the first condition of an Logical Or-operation already evaluates to true, there is no need to check the second one.

Comment: Commenting a decade after the response...
It isn't really a contrast with other languages, but other operators. VB's `Or` is equivalent to C#'s `|` (single pipe, bitwise OR operator). Both C# and VB.NET have bitwise and short-circuiting logical operators.

Comment: @Darryl: yes, VB.NET does also have bitwise and short-circuiting logic operators - but the difference is that C# does short-circuiting by default whereas in VB.NET you have to use OrElse/AndAlso. That's what I meant. Maybe the part about VB.NET was a bit redundant in regards to the question.

Comment: What you consider to be the "default" depends on what you're used to typing. In VB code I've written, and what I've seen in other people's code, `AndAlso` outnumbers `And` 100 to 1, and it's what automatically comes flowing out of my fingers by habit. If I were in the bad/incorrect habit of using `|` in C# where `||` is more appropriate, I could say that C#'s default behavior is not short circuiting either. It all comes down to appropriate choice of operators, not a language difference.

Answer (score 0):

may be this would be useful in your example:

```
List<FSKUser> users = null;
return users != null && users.Any();
```