# C# Null propagating operator / Conditional access expression & if blocks

Tags: c#, null, language-features, c#-6.0

The [Null propagating operator / Conditional access expression](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883) coming in [c#-6.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) looks like quite a handy feature.  But I'm curious if it will help solve the problem of checking if a child member is not null and then calling a Boolean method on said child member inside an if block:

```
  public class Container<int>{
       IEnumerable<int> Objects {get;set;}
  }

  public Container BuildContainer()
  { 
      var c = new Container();

      if (/* Some Random Condition */)
         c.Objects = new List<int>{1,2,4};
  }

  public void Test()
  {
      var c = BuildContainer();

      //Old way
      if ( null != c && null != c.Objects && c.Objects.Any())
         Console.Write("Container has items!");


      //C# 6 way?
      if (c?.Object?.Any())
          Console.Write("Container has items!");
  }
```

Will `c?.Object?.Any()` compile?  If the propagating operator short circuits (I assume that's the right term) to null then you have `if (null)`, which isn't valid.

Will the C# team address this concern or am I missing the intended use case for the null propagating operator?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It won't work this way. You can just skip the explanation and see the code below :)

As you know `?.` operator will return null if a child member is null. But what happens if we try to get a non-nullable member, like the `Any()` method, that returns `bool`? The answer is that the compiler will "wrap" a return value in `Nullable<>`. For example, `Object?.Any()` will give us `bool?` (which is `Nullable<bool>`), not `bool`.

The only thing that doesn't let us use this expression in the `if` statement is that it can't be implicitly casted to `bool`. But you can do comparison explicitly, I prefer comparing to `true` like this:

```
if (c?.Object?.Any() == true)
    Console.Write("Container has items!");
```

[Thanks to @DaveSexton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666993/c-sharp-null-propagating-operator-conditional-access-expression-if-blocks#comment40112558_25667306) there's another way:

```
if (c?.Object?.Any() ?? false)
    Console.Write("Container has items!");
```

But as for me, comparison to `true` seems more natural :)

Comment: So `?.` doesn't actually return null?  It returns a `Nullable`?

Comment: @PhilipPittle it wraps return value in `Nullable` for value and primitive types

Comment: Alternatively, some may prefer to use the null coalescing operator: `if (c?.Objects?.Any() ?? false) { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

Null-conditional operator would return `null` or the value at the end of expression. For [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) It will return result in `Nullable<T>`, so in your case it would be `Nullabe<bool>`. If we look at the example in the document for [Upcoming Features in C#](https://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=roslyn&DownloadId=894944) *(specified [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552378))*, it has an example:

```
int? first = customers?[0].Orders.Count();
```

In the above example, instead of `int`, `Nullable<int>` would be returned. For `bool` it will return `Nullable<bool>`.

If you try the following code in [Visual Studio "14" CTP](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs.aspx):

```
Nullable<bool> ifExist = c?.Objects?.Any();
```

The result of the above line would be a `Nullable<bool>`/`bool?`. Later you can do the comparison like:

Using [null-coalescing operator ??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
 if (c?.Object?.Any() ?? false)
```

Using [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

```
if ((c?.Objects?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault())
```

Using comparison against `true`

```
if (c?.Objects?.Any() == true)
```

Answer (score 2):

`var x = c?.Objects?.Any()` is going to give you a nullable boolean, and as others have said, this means you can use an equality operator like this

```
x == true
```

or you can use null coalescing like this to have your result not be nullable

```
var x = c?.Objects?.Any() ?? false
```

But, personally, I think that 3-state (nullable) booleans are code smell. Even if this one is practically invisible, its existence should encourage you to think about what you are actually trying to do and determine if a nullable boolean is actually the way to go. In this case, I think that what you really want to do is something like this -

```
var objects = c?.Objects ?? Enumerable.Empty<Object>();
if (objects.Any())
{
 ...
}
```

Put that in an extension method and it will be even more succinct -

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
   return !(collection ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).Any()
}
```