# MySQL Entity Framework With LinQ Correlated Query Not Executing

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with MySQL 5.7 Community Edition. I am getting object reference not set to an instance of object on the below query.

```
var oList = (
    from dm in dbContext.document_master
    join um in dbContext.user_master on dm.Alocated_CAA equals um.UserId
    where (dm.DocumentHandle != null)
    select new TaskLogReport
    {
        documentDate = dm.Document_Date,
        documentHandle = dm.DocumentHandle,
        fileNumber = dm.FileNumber,
        statusRemarks = dbContext.statushistories
            .Where(x => x.DocumentHandle == 12345678).FirstOrDefault().Remarks
    }).ToList();
```

In the above query If I get change 12345678 to dm.DocumentHandle, then getting object reference not set to an instance object.

Try with MS-SQL server , working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `FirstOrDefault()` returns null, because there are no objects who's `DocumentHandle` equals `dm.DocumentHandle`. Changing `dm.DocumentHandle` to `12345678` works because there is one matching element.

This line is the problem:

```
.Where(x => x.DocumentHandle == 12345678).FirstOrDefault().Remarks
```

C#'s [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns either the first matching element of an enumerable, or, if there aren't any, the default value of the type. In the case of nullable types, `FirstOrDefault()` returns null if no elements are found.

The reason you get no error when you use `12345678` is because there is at least one matching value with that `DocumentHandle`. However, when you change that to `dm.DocumentHandle`, no matching elements are found, causing `FirstOrDefault` to return `null`. Then you essentially do `null.Remarks`, which causes the error.

You should change your code to this:

```
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentHandle == dm.DocumentHandle)?.Remarks
```

There are two differences here:

1. Got rid of the where and moved the predicate to the `FirstOrDefault` call. This is just a cleaner way of doing what you were doing before.
2. Added the `?` at the end of the `FirstOrDefault` call. That is the [null propagation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666993/c-sharp-null-propagating-operator-conditional-access-expression-if-blocks).

What it does is it turns this:

```
int foo;
if (bar != null)
{
    foo = bar.foo;
}
```

Into this:

```
int foo = bar?.foo;
```

Now, if there are matching elements, `statusRemarks` will be equal to the first one's `Remarks`. Otherwise, `statusRemarks` will be `null`.

**EDIT:** The null propagation operator was implemented in C# 6.0, which is .Net 4.6 onwards, so it won't work in .Net 4.0.

You'll have to modify your query and implement a check, like so:

```
var oList = (
    from dm in dbContext.document_master
    join um in dbContext.user_master on dm.Alocated_CAA equals um.UserId
    where (dm.DocumentHandle != null && dbContext.statushistories.Count(x => x.DocumentHandle == dm.DocumentHandle) > 0)
    select new TaskLogReport
    {
        documentDate = dm.Document_Date,
        documentHandle = dm.DocumentHandle,
        fileNumber = dm.FileNumber,
        statusRemarks = dbContext.statushistories.First(x.DocumentHandle == dm.DocumentHandle).Remarks
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am using .Net Framework 4.0 & null programming operator not working. After replicating the same code set on MS-SQL 2005 , it's working properly and the same code is not working with MySQL. I tried to install different connector but persists same isssue