# Null-propagation replacement for null check prior conditional statement

Tags: c#, null, language-features, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

After seeing a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666993/c-sharp-null-propagating-operator-conditional-access-expression-if-blocks), I was wondering if the following expression ...

```
if (attribute != null && attribute.Description == input)
```

... would behave (almost) identical, to following null-propagation variant?

```
if (attribute?.Description == input)
```

So far, I could determine only following (somehow minor) differences:

- not possible in case `input` is of non-nullable type
- in case `input` would be itself `null`, behavior would be altered

Am I missing something? or are there other differences *in behavior*?

---

**EDIT:** in the end, the only fail-safe alternative I've found for the first snippet, would be:

```
if (attribute?.Description?.Equals(input) ?? false)
```

Comment: `attribute` is only evaluated once in the second case, so you can never get a `NullReferenceException`. In the first case, if `attribute` is changed from non-null to null after the evaluation of the first condition but before the evaluation of the second, you'll still see an exception...

Comment: If you don't want to allow `input` to be `null` you should check that first. Then there's no difference because a nullable can be compared with a non-nullable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That doesn't actually help you.  The point is that the two snippets *behave* differently when `input` is null, and they do so in such a way that, for the second snippet, you can't just check for it first; you would need to refactor the second snippet into something akin to the first in order for it to return the right result if `input` is allowed to be `null`.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing what a question is asking after getting an answer to that question.

Comment: @Servy Ok, sorry for that. I was thinking to keep there an updated list, where to add/remove differences. Also thought that the first wrong statement of the list could misleading others, if they won't read the answer. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code *will* work if `input` is of a non-nullable type.  There is an implicit conversion of all non-nullable types to their nullable counterparts, so `input` will simply be lifted to a nullable to be compared to the property value.

The only difference in behavior, as you mentioned is that, if `input` is `null`, then the second snippet has no way of differentiating between `attribute` being `null`, when it should be `false`, and where `Description` is `null`, where it should be `true`.

Oh, and this is assuming that `attribute` is a local variable or field.  If it's a property (or is actually a more complex expression) then it could have side effects or result in a different value when computed twice, as happens in the first snippet but not the second, which is a difference in behavior.

This is all of course assuming a single threaded context.  In a multithreaded context, if `attribute` is accessible from another thread (either because it's a field that's accessible or because it's closed over in a lambda that is exposed to another thread) then the value could be different each time it's computed, so the two snippets differ for the same reason described in the previous paragraph.

Comment: How do you know if its never `null`? Working with contracts?

Comment: In my case, input comes from a predefined config file.