# How can I check wether an array contains any item or is completely empty?

Tags: c#, arrays

If I define an integer array:

```
int[] a = new int[13];
```

and I do not insert any item into it, how can I know whether the array a contains any items or is completely empty?
Do I have to iterate through all the a.Length indices?
In a list

```
List<int> b = new List<int>();
```

if I check:

```
if(b.Count == 0)
{
    // The list does not contain any items.
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to check an array?
I found on the internet the check if an array is null or empty.
In my case I know for sure that the array is not null.
I just wish to know whether it contains any item or not.
I do not care in which position within the array and also not exactly which item. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560106/isnullorempty-equivalent-for-array-c-sharp

Comment: Leave array out of it if you are going to dynamically scale the collection. If so happens that you already know the length provide that number into List of ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] a = new int[13]; // [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

allocates a array with 13 items. The value of each item is `0` or `default(int)`.

So you have to check

```
bool isEmpty =  a.All(x => x == default(int));
```

If `0` is a valid value within your array, you should use nullable type:

```
int?[] a = new int?[13]; // [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
bool isEmpty =  a.All(x => !x.HasValue);
```

Comment: That is underterministing. What if all actual values are defaults of type.

Comment: @fubo Doesn't cover my case. Array is not a correct collection type for the task.

Comment: @Karolis as already mentioned, in that case `int` isn't the right type for the array

Comment: @fubo In any case default value of any type is indeterministic. Whether you wrap it into nullable or not.

Comment: Example is good! There is just an extra comma at the end of the nullable array declaration comment ;-)

Comment: dont forget to add import:  using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1):

Since its an integer, you can check if all values are zero:

```
if (array.All(y=>y == 0))
  {
    //If all values are zero, this will proceed on this statement.       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array like this:

```
int[] a = new int[13];
```

you get an array that contains 13 elements. All of them have the value zero because that's the default value for an int.

So what you could do is:

```
bool hasElements = a.Any(x => x != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class which encapsulates the `Array` class and keeps track of whether the array has been changed yet or not.

```
public class MyArray<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    private bool altered = false;

    public MyArray(int size)
    {
        array= new T[size + 1];
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        set
        {
            altered = true;
            array[index] = value;
        }

    }

    public bool HasBeenAltered()
    {
        return altered;
    }
}
```

The function `HasBeenAltered()` tells whether any item of the array has been updated.

```
MyArray<int> arr = new MyArray<int>(10);
arr.HasBeenAltered(); // false

arr[4] = 4;
arr.HasBeenAltered(); // true
```

Comment: Not a problem. PS. If the answer suits your needs please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.